# Transferring and displaying image from remote location

Tags: php

I need to read an image (based on HTTP) on an SSL connection. This script reads the image location and encodes/decodes it, then transfers the file contents and returns the image. However, I keep getting the error `cannot be displayed because it contains errors`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php   
$image = 'http://www.teleovronnaz.ch/webcam/ovronnazweb.jpg';

$info = getimagesize($image);
$strFileExt = image_type_to_extension($info[2]);

  if($strFileExt == '.jpg' or $strFileExt == '.jpeg'){
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  }elseif($strFileExt == '.png'){
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
  }elseif($strFileExt == '.gif'){
    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
  }else{
    die('not supported');
  }
  if($strFile != ''){
    $cache_ends = 60*60*24*365;
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Cache-Control: maxage=". $cache_ends);
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $cache_ends).' GMT');

$img_safe = file_get_contents($strFile);
echo $img_safe;
  }
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. Is there any logs that you could provide us?

Comment: The code works fine, but when I access the script directly I get the error : cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the script directly"?

Comment: ... when I execute the script.

Comment: You mean executing the script by opening it in browser or calling it from another php file?

Comment: Opening it in the browser

Comment: I opened php file containing your code directly from browser (Firefox 64.0) and the image shows correctly without any errors. You may want to check if your server can connect to the site containing that image.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.teleovronnaz.ch/webcam/ovronnazweb.jpg';
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you do it so complicated. I just stripped your cache handling, but really

```
<?PHP
$image = 'http://www.teleovronnaz.ch/webcam/ovronnazweb.jpg';
$imageContent = file_get_contents($image);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $imageContent;
die(1);
?>
```

Is enough to display the image. No `base64` or additional stuff needed. And if the url is static, you don't even need the distinction of the file extension. You stated an image - that's singular. So I'm guessing that's the only use case here.

---

I just took some more time to explain a few things:

> read an image (based on HTTP) on an SSL connection

If it's `HTTP`, there is **no SSL**. That's what `HTTPS` is for.

> This script reads the image location and encodes/decodes it,

I don't know what you think, but it is not. It is base64_encoding the URL to directly decode it again into another variable. That's like doing the following: `0` is your `$image` - then you make `$image+1` (`base64_encode`) - which will result in `1` - then you do `$image-1` (`base64_decode`) which will result in `0` again.

Comment: I meant images and the location needs to be extracted from the Url. I need base64 here..

Comment: @mark - then really give us your use cases. But really, the lines with base64 are so useless. That's like wrapping a gift to directly unwrap it.

Comment: the encoding part will be placed in the script serving the image.

Comment: I am really sorry, but either you completely fail to articulate what you want to achieve or you have no clue what you're doing.

Comment: the part that is important here is displaying the (external)image knowing that it could either be jpg/jpeg or png. The base  64 is not very relevant here (unless the process of encoding and decoding fails here)

Comment: I am really giving up on this one.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Maio290. Have a great 2019!